# Discontinuous linear function

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Consider the set of all real-valued functions defined on the integers. This is a vector space over the reals with the obvious definition of addition and scalar multiplication. We can consider this a topological space as the set of doubly infinite real sequences with the product topology.

Is there a linear transformation from this set to itself which is not continuous?

Comment: Yes. We can give the space a complete norm, and it's infinite-dimensional, so there exists an unbounded linear map from the space to itself.

Comment: @AJY: Is it possible to construct an explicit example? I tried searching, but I am probably not using the right keywords.

Comment: @AJY: I fear that the space is not normable since no neighbourhood of the origin is bounded...

Comment: @haemi You're right. I was going to come back to this and see if I could cook up such a map explicitly.

Comment: Any linear transformation mapping $e_n$ to $n\cdot e_0$ where $e_n=(\delta_{mn})_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}$ (using the Kronecker delta notation) should do the trick, doesn't it?

Comment: @AJY: sorry, I forgot to put the notification syntax into my last comment and can't seem to include it via edit now...

Comment: @haemi If $T(e_n) = n e_0$ then shouldn't we have $T((x_k)) = (\sum_{k} k x_k) e_0$ which may not make sense.

Comment: @ArinChaudhuri: what do you mean by $x_k$?

Comment: @haemi I meant the doubly infinite series $(\dots,x_{-m},\dots,x_{-1},x_0,x_1,\dots)$.

Comment: @ArinChaudhuri ah right, I lost track of all the brackets :) the problem you described does not occur since $T$ only has to be compatible with FINITE sums - that's in fact the idea behind my construction. I'll whip up an answer shortly!

Comment: @haemi  Ah I get it. $z_n$ where $z_n(k) = x_k$ if $|k| \leq n$ and $z_n(k) = 0$ otherwise converges to $(x_k)$ pointwise and hence in product topology. If there exists a $T$ with $T(e_n) = ne_0$ and if it is continuous, we must have $T(z_n) = T(\sum_{k=-n}^{n} x_k e_k ) =  (\sum_{k=-n}^{n} k x_k )e_0$ must converge to $T(z)$. This implies, $\sum_{k=-n}^{n} k x_k$ must converge for all $(x_k)$ which is wrong. So such a $T$ if it exists is not continuous. Now, I have no idea how to construct such a $T$ explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the sequences $f_n:=(\delta_{mn})_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}$. They are linearly independent, hence - by basic linear algebra - there is a (algebraic, or "Hamel-") basis $B$ of our space (calling it $X$ from now on) which includes all the $f_n$. Therefore there exists a (unique) linear mapping $T$ from $X$ in itself with $T(f_n)=|n|\cdot f_0$ and $T(g)=0$ for each $g\in B\setminus\{f_n:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. Now, arguing as the OP in a comment, $T$ cannot be continuous: the sequence of sequences $(y_m)_m=((z_{mn})_{n\in\mathbb{Z}})_{m\in\mathbb{N}}$ where $z_{mn}=1$ iff $|n|\leq m$, else 0 converges pointwise, hence wrt the product topology, to $(1)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$. Hence $(T(y_m))_{m\in\mathbb{N}}=((\sum_{|n|\leq m}|n|)\cdot e_0)_{m\in\mathbb{N}}$ must converge wrt the product topology, especially pointwise. Consider the 0-component, $(\sum_{|n|\leq m}|n|)_{m\in\mathbb{N}}$, which evidently doesn't converge.